# Truncate firebase items by a specific field

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner to iOS and Swift and cant seem to truncate a list of database comments to only show comments which are currently active.

Comments have an endtimestamp field that is an int eg: 1507522353

Here is the area of code that fetches 10+ comments:

```
commentsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  self.comments.append(snapshot)
  self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.comments.count-1, section: self.kSectionComments)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
})
```

I want to only append (and display) the comments that endtimestamp < current timestamp

Thanks

Comment: Your question is bit unclear, please add more information. What is expected, what have you tried and what is the result of current implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to achieve this using `queryEnding(atValue:)`, where the value is the current timestamp in milliseconds minus one. The query is ordered by `endtimestamp` so to specify the child key for the ending at value query.

```
let now = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0
let query = commentsRef
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "endtimestamp")
    .queryEnding(atValue: now - 1)

query.observe(.childAdded, ...
```